# What values does Disperse.app's disperse function parameters look like?

Tags: etherscan

[image]

So the etherscan's write function looks like this, I've tried submitting:

1. 0.05
2. address1,address2,address3,address4,address5
3. 10000000000000000

and the contract won't accept it, does anyone know where I am making a mistake here?

Answer (score 0):

you need to put the adresses inside an array, so it would look like `[address1, address2, address3...]`, and same thing for the values, so that would be [valueForAddress1, valueForAddress2....].
And i dont know that specific dApp but i assume disperseEther should be (at least) equal to the sum of all the values